# Conditional removal of rows for grouped data in R

Tags: r, nested, row, mean

I'm trying to extract the annual mean rainfall for every year between 1950-2015 for several gauge stations. The rainfall dataset is made up of daily measurements.

Before calculating the annual mean for each individual station, I need to filter the data, so that every month must have >15 days-worth of data.

How could this be done in R?

Let this be a working example:

```
id<-rep(c("Station_1","Station_2","Station_3"),length(1),each=1080)
year<-rep(c(1950:1952),length(1:3),each=360)
month <- rep(c(1:12),length(1:9),each=30)
day <- rep(c(1:30),length(1:108))
value<-runif(3240, min=0, max=10)

df<-data.frame(cbind(id,year,month,day,value))
```

I tried something like:

```
result<-df %>%
   group_by(id,year,month) %>%
   summarise(No._of_days=n(),mean_month=mean(value))
result<-result[!(result$No._of_days<15),]
result<-result %>%
   group_by(id,year) %>%
   summarise(No._of_months=n(),mean_year=mean(mean_month))
```

However this leads to the wrong solution as I'm taking "a mean from a mean".

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Please stop using `data.frame(cbind(...))`. `data.frame()` is sufficient. Have a look at `?data.frame`.

Comment: Thank you Sathish, aichao, sebolus and NJBurgo for your quick and correct replies - your help is very much appreciated! All solutions work, but I'll stick with aichao's simply as I'm most comfortable using dplyr.

Sorry about incorrectly formulating the dataframe - I'll leave "as is" now because everyone here has added good comment on how to structure it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Raw data:** Remove the default factoring of variables while creating data frames.

```
df<-data.frame(id = id,year = year, month = month, day = day, value = value, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Group the data by `id, year, month` and get the number of days for the subset using `.N` internal variable. Next, chain the results (similar to %>% in dplyr). Now group-by `id, year`, followed by the condition `N > 15` and finally the `mean` rainfall for that subset is computed and stored in `avg_rainfall`.

`setDT` converts dataframe to datatable by reference

```
library("data.table")
setDT(df)[, .(value, .N), by = .(id, year, month)][N > 15, .(avg_rainfall = mean(value)), by = .(id, year)]

#           id year avg_rainfall
# 1: Station_1 1950     4.852840
# 2: Station_1 1951     5.138069
# 3: Station_1 1952     4.934006
# 4: Station_2 1950     4.870335
# 5: Station_2 1951     5.179425
# 6: Station_2 1952     5.055026
# 7: Station_3 1950     4.959524
# 8: Station_3 1951     5.049996
# 9: Station_3 1952     4.927548
```

Comment: thank you very much for your quick and clear solution - I really appreciate it! Apologies about incorrectly formulating the dataframe - will bare in mind for next time.

Comment: one more question, rather than filtering rows which have > 15 days, can I instead filter if 15 consecutive cells are NAs? E.g..... df[ ,!apply(is.na(df), 2, function(x)
{v <- cumsum(x); any(diff(v, 2) == 2)})].....  I will update my question if needed. Adapted from this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15186697/conditional-row-removal-based-on-number-of-nas-within-the-row

Comment: If your intention is to remove NA before computing the mean, you could pass `na.rm = TRUE` inside the mean function. For example: `avg_rainfall = mean(value, na.rm = TRUE)`

Answer (score 1):

A few things, the example data.frame, because of how you created it, codes everything as a factor. Use this instead:

```
df<-data.frame(id = id,
               year = year,
               month = month,
               day = day,
               value = value)
```

Then (and I am sorry, I am not a `magrittr` fan) the following will work:

```
# Filter into a new data.frame
df2 <- semi_join(df, 
          filter(summarise(group_by(df, year, month), N = n()), N > 15),
          by = c(year = "year", 
                 month = "month"))

# Summarise
summarise(group_by(df2, id), 
          value = mean(value, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: Thanks @NJBurgo, for the great solution and quick response to the question! Cheers, C

Answer (score 0):

Focusing only on the code, it works for me, with some modifications. E.g. you write that you want > 15days of data, but select >14, also make sure values are numeric, not factor in your df.

```
`df<-data.frame(cbind(id,year,month,day,value))
 df$value<- as.numeric(as.character(df$value))
   result<-df %>%
   group_by(id,year,month) %>%
   summarise(No._of_days=n(),mean_month=mean(value))
result<-result[!(result$No._of_days<=15),]
result<-result %>%
  group_by(id,year) %>%
  summarise(No._of_months=n(),mean_year=mean(mean_month))`
```

Code aside: From a mathematical perspective this approach is not clear to me. Why would you want to exlude everything that has less than 16 measurements for the yearly Aggregation? If the presence of your measurements is truely at random, consider to use the values that you have for any month and impute all missing days in your dataset (e.g. using Regression for each Station, year (continuous), calendarweek, rainfall on previous and following day).

Comment: Thanks @sebolus for your solution - I really appreciate the quick turnaround. Re. the maths, my subsetting method is done because seasonal differences in rainfall across the year might be lost if some months are poorly represented in formulating the annual mean. Though your imputing solution is feasible, a common method used in existing literature on rainfall/wind/temp data etc. is to simply exclude those months (and then years if necessary) to avoid this issue. For the moment, I'll stick with the subsetting approach. Thanks, Cai

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different approach using `dplyr` and `magrittr`:

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(42) # this is only so we get consistent results to compare

# then generate id, year month, day, and value using your code 
# but use what @NJBurgo used to generate df

df<-data.frame(id = id,
       year = year,
       month = month,
       day = day,
       value = value)

result <- df %>%
  group_by(id,year,month) %>%
  mutate(No._of_days=n()) %>%
  filter(No._of_days > 15) %>%  ## keep only rows with number of days greater than 15
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(id,year) %>%
  summarize(mean_year=mean(value))

# using set.seed(42), you should get
print(result)
##         id  year mean_year
##     <fctr> <int>     <dbl>
##1 Station_1  1950  4.954538
##2 Station_1  1951  4.878709
##3 Station_1  1952  4.737996
##4 Station_2  1950  4.942614
##5 Station_2  1951  4.876992
##6 Station_2  1952  5.193242
##7 Station_3  1950  5.235278
##8 Station_3  1951  4.955401
##9 Station_3  1952  4.905078
```

The key is to `filter` the `group_by` rows (grouped by `id`, `year`, and `month`). I also used `mutate` instead of `summarise` to create `No._of_days`. Then `ungroup()` and then regroup by `id` and `year` to compute the mean.

BTW, your test case is not sufficient to test this because all months have `30` days.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @aichao - I like this solution, especially as I'm most comfortable working with dplyr.

Point taken about the dataframe - I thought it important to include an example to go by, even if it was a poor one! I hadn't made a dummy dataset before and didn't want to spend too long finding out how to create a more realistic replication of the real data, knowing the concept of filtering by no of days would still hold true.

Many thanks